# AJAX get PHP source

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm well aware why this is dangerous. The AJAX request comes from the same server and domain as the PHP file.

I have a PHP file which I wish to get the contents of the source via an AJAX request. Is this possible on a PHP enabled server, and if so how?

Comment: Call a script that does `readfile('myfile.php');`?

Comment: Horribly bad solution: turn on `.phps` support, allowing anyone to get the source of ANY php script on your server.

Comment: @MarkBaker I was responding to your comment before it was edited. As in I thought you were saying I should just `readfile()` instead of AJAX. Hence why I deleted it when you edited.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and works

call a php page with following code

```
 <?php
   echo readfile("your_file.php");
 ?>
```

it will output the raw php

Answer (score 0):

If you are already aware that this is dangerous, then you should use functions like, [readfile](http://www.php.net/readfile), [file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) or [fgets](http://www.php.net/fgets)